# How can I get an hp laserjet 1000 printer to work with 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, printer, hp-laserjet

Lots of people are asking this question but I haven't found an answer anywhere,.

Comment: an hour later, and I'm prettyh convinced it's not doable, especially because the printer uses what's called a "host based driver".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make HP Laserjet 1000 drivers work on Windows 7 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/91474/how-to-make-hp-laserjet-1000-drivers-work-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have a LaserJet 1012 that i got working with Win7 RC (64-bit) by picking a similar driver (1015, i think). i did the same in Vista. but now i'm not seeing it in the RTM version so i'm also stuck. :(

if you can find and pick the 1015 driver through Device Manager it's worth a shot.

<rant>

given that my HP 1012 printer was manufactured in 2004 and Vista came out in 2006 (with widespread beta in 2005) and HP didn't even support Vista, i've added HP to my blacklist. i fought with getting drivers from within months of buying the stupid thing and will never again buy an HP product.

that level of support is ridiculous, especially for something like a printer and ESPECIALLY since people (including myself) were able to get it to work through trickery... until now at least, suggesting it would have taken HP little work to provide a real driver.

i'm sorry, but laser printers shouldn't be forced into obsolescence after only one or two years.

</rant>

~jewels

Comment: The line that makes this the accepted answer is "I've added HP to my blacklist".   I'm buying a new printer, not HP.

Comment: +1 for "I've added HP to my blacklist". I too am appalled that HP have not produced Vista/7 drivers for the HP 1000/1010 range.

Comment: Totally agree with ctrager. It's dirty behaviour. The PC companies do it, too -- bought an XP machine? No Vista drivers for you, sorry. Buy a new machine. FAIL.

Answer (score 1):

I've scoured through Google searches without a result.   Interesting problem.

Not having an HP LJ1000 to play with, I can only suggest that perhaps try drivers for more recent LJ's?

I've gotten lucky that my Epson printers work great with Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that laserjet 1000 is not even Vista compatible. Furthermore, it has been discontinued.

There is a [workaround](http://www.softwaretipsandtricks.com/forum/windows-vista/31175-hp-laserjet-1000-not-working.html) for Vista 32-bits that will also work for Windows 7, but not for 64-bits.

AFAIK, your options are as follows:

1. You might make the printer work in XP mode and share it. I have no experience with that.
2. You might use [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or Virtual PC to construct a 32-bits XP virtual machine, install the printer and share it. This might still not work without lots of fiddling.

I think the first option is the best, if it works.
If not, you could maybe instead convert to the 32-bits version of Windows 7, for which there is a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.   What are the steps to "make the printer work in XP mode"?    

(Converting to the 32-bit version of windows for the sake of a $90 printer would be the tail wagging the dog...)

Comment: If XP mode is installed, you can get to it via Start Menu -> All Programs -> Windows Virtual PC -> Windows XP Mode (or maybe just type XP in the Start menu). You should be presented with a standard XP SP3 desktop. I got all that info from here : http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial155.html.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to reply to the other answer, but for the guy who was talking about the LaserJet 1012.  There is a Vista 64-bit driver that you can install in Windows 7.  I have this printer and have done this.  You do have to explicitly choose the driver and it will warn you about it, but it works.

[HP LaserJet 1012 vista 64 driver](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=306510&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=377934&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=2100)

Answer (score 0):

From memory, the Hp LJ1000 is almost EXACTLY the same as the LJ1200.  Not sure that makes a difference, but it there it is.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by saving the Vista driver from the HP site to my machine, then going into the saved file and unzipping it, and resaving it.  When adding the device through Devices and Printers, you need to click Have Disk, then browse for the unzipped file.  The port has to be selected as DOT4_001GenericIEEE.  Even though the 1015 was selected as the printer in Devices and Printers, the icon now calls it the 1010, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I know how.
You download your driver or copy the files from the old install cd.  Then you go to the setup file in that and rt click it.  Go to the compatability tab on the window that opens and rell it to work with your version of windows up to like xp or such.  Close the window. Rt click the file again n tell it to run as administrator.  Close and the doubleclick your install file.
Its called compatability mode guys n it is in win 7 ultimate and any later windows os..

Enjoy