# How to make HP Laserjet 1000 drivers work on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, hp-laserjet

I know that HP has no intention of providing driver support for older model printers (their web site solution is telling me to buy a new printer).

However, is there a work-around that will allow me to use the HP LJ 1000 printer in Windows 7 (64bit)?  What about a "generic" driver for the LaserJet?  Any suggestions?  Will I need to trick Windows into accepting the printer?

Comment: Did you try the "HP Laserjet Family PCL5" driver (it is part of my Win 7 Ultimate distro)? My dad has a Laserjet 1000 so I'll have him try this and update my post per what happens.

Comment: Along the same lines, I've got an HP LaserJet 1320. After too much fooling around trying to find a workable PostScript driver for it, I installed "HP Universal Printing PCL 5" (probably downloaded from HP, though I don't recall). It's worked w/o problems. There are probably a few obscure printer features that I can't access with this driver, but nothing I've missed.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I found a solution posted in *[Driver needed: Hewlett Packard (HP) HP Laserjet 1000 Series (Windows XP Professional x64) (USB)](http://forums.driverguide.com/showthread.php?t=46368&page=2)*.

But you **are not** going to like it.

Pretty much the rundown is that Hewlett-Packard never built a 64-bit driver base for this and several other printers that are host controlled. So the solution is to either setup the printer on a 32-bit machine, use settings to print from DOS, and then share it. From the Windows Vista/Windows 7 machine connect to the share and install the HP 1100 driver provided in the printer list.

OR

Install the [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) software provided in the links on that forum on your 64-bit box. Then install the printer in the 32-bit environment, and set it up as a share. Connect to the internally shared printer on the VirtualBox instance that is running on your 64-bit box.

Best of luck in this endeavor.

Answer (score 2):

With some versions of Windows 7 you get to use a tool called XP Mode. Check here for details: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

You must have a processor capable of running it. "AMD-V and Intel VT are CPU-specific hardware virtualization features that must be enabled to utilize Windows Virtual PC."

Windows XP Mode, a single virtual copy of Windows XP Service Pack 3, is available for download free of charge from http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx for PCs running Windows 7 Professional, Windows 7 Ultimate, and Windows 7 Enterprise.

Source: Microsoft.com

You coould just connect to the XP machine using the ip address. Goto run type \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\ and right click on the pinter and click connect. That would be the easiest way of cponnecting to your Xp printer.

Comment: This is just another way to run virtual OS inside the main OS. Works, yes, but it's a bit overkill for just one printer.

Comment: I guess that depends is you really need to use that printer. I guess its for the user to decide.

Answer (score 0):

For me when I has a scanner that wasn't supported, I was in luck and I was able to use a virtual machine and load an OS that had a driver for it.  You may need to jump through those kind of hoops if new OSs don't support devices you want to keep using.

Good luck.

(ps: I thought from their website that there was a driver, but are right HP didn't support it.)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a driver issue for an older piece of hardware (a scanner) and I decided to try the Vista driver. It worked great. I just did some quick research on the HP site and it doesn't look like the Vista driver is available. You could try a driver for another similar (supported) printer

Answer (score 0):

LaserJet 1000 works on all 32 bit Windows operating systems, but not a 64 bit ones. I installed it on Windows 7, 8 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

To use your still-kicking HP LaserJet 1000 with a Windows 7 system, you'll need a workaround.

Open a new browser window and visit Konica Minolta Business Solutions. Locate the driver for "Magicolor 2430DL-Drivers-Windows 7 64-bit" and click "Show" to display the drivers for download. No, these drivers are not specifically designed for the HP LaserJet 1000, but Konica's printer drivers are generic and will get your HP working in Windows 7.

Here's a link to the complete instructions:

https://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/hook-up-computer-printers-9634.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).